# Twitter Bootstrap - sample app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to java script, but got very impressed with twitter bootstrap. i would like to use boot strap and create some samples.

when i am including the js for button etc given by bootsrap , not found working.

Please could i get a sample login page with a mix of html,java script using twitter bootstrap.

I would also like to know how to refer to bootstrap components in html -> java script.

I want a conmprehensive login example to start with, i have already downloaded the twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with you, Twitter Bootstrap is quite an amazing framework, especially when you need to start building a sleek website quickly and effectively. There is many ways to create a login page using Bootstrap, but ultimately, you cannot just create it with HTML and JavaScript, you would need some sort of server-side script that would authenticate the user. The best way to do this is by using PHP. JavaScript is not required for a login form unless you want to create some method of client-side validation before the data is passed along to the server. It's not required to do this although.

For an example, you would have your basic login form `login.php`...

```
<form id="loginForm" action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="span4" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="span4" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

This would be your basic login form (customize as needed). As you can see, it posts the entered data to `login.php` which is the same file the above form would be on.

In order to validate the user input and log the person in, you would need to use a script or write a script in PHP that retrieves the data posted by the form and authenticates the user. Assuming your question, you are not too familiar with PHP, which will make it much more difficult. Your best bet in this case would be to find a free login script or members script on the web written in PHP and modify it to your needs and use the classes/structure for Bootstrap.

If you are interested in validating user input via JavaScript before posting the data to the php script, I would suggest that you look into jQuery. Bootstrap was written to use jQuery so it integrates well. jQuery is also very easy to learn when you have a basic understanding of JavaScript.

Hopefully this helps you build a login form as needed.